# How can I use a list of variables in the "EXECUTE STATEMENT USING" statement MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the below procedure -

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testInjection $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testInjection(IN groupList LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
SET @groupList = groupList;
SET @QUERY = "SELECT * FROM ben where groupid IN ? ";
PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt USING @groupList;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
```

'**groupList**' is a list of long variables. When calling the above procedure, I get the MySQL syntax error near 'where groupid in '?' '.

Looking on the Internet, I found that `?` is a placeholder just for single variable and so we cannot use it for the list. Even if I create multiple `?` variable like "?,?,?" and append it to the `mysql` query. How am I supposed to use the **@groupList** variable in "**EXECUTE STATEMENT USING**" statement?

I am calling the procedure as below -

```
CALL testInjection('(6598924, 6598928)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When parsing a comma separated values as a input to a`IN` it will be considered as a string, so we need to use `find_in_set`.

Try the below query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testInjection(IN groupList LONGTEXT)
BEGIN
SET @groupList = groupList;
SET @QUERY = 'select * from ben where find_in_set (groupid,?)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @QUERY;
EXECUTE stmt USING @groupList; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;  
END $$
```

**To Call:**
`call testInjection('6598924, 6598928');`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below query ...

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE

IF EXISTS testInjection $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE testInjection (IN groupList LONGTEXT)

BEGIN
    SET @groupList = groupList;
    SET @QUERY = "SELECT * FROM ben where groupid IN @groupList ";

    PREPARE stmt
    FROM @QUERY;

    EXECUTE stmt USING @groupList;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
```

Comment: Why are you using @groupList two times ?